# Boot Menu won't boot USB for Debian install

Tags: debian, boot, live-usb, thinkpad

I'm trying to install Debian Jessie on my Lenovo Thinkpad Yoga II. I created a usb using UNetBootin with the ISO image, and when I start my laptop with the usb in, the "Boot Menu" comes up, it gives me the option to boot from "USB HDD: SanDisk Cruzer Glide" but it doesn't actually start the installation process- it just cuts to black quickly and then brings up the boot menu again.
Any idea what could be my problem?
Thanks

Comment: The first thing https://unetbootin.github.io/ mentions is formatting the USB stick as FAT32. How is your USB stick formatted?

Comment: Also, some troubleshooting tips - http://smallbusiness.chron.com/troubleshoot-iso-unetbootin-63577.html

Comment: Doing a search for alternatives gives https://alternativeto.net/software/unetbootin/

Comment: I used Disk Utility in Mac Os X to format it to Fats/Master Boot Record.

Comment: I decided to switch over to my desktop that I run CentOS on. I formatted the usb using the terminal to FAT32, and then I used sudo dd if=/iso of=/dev/sdb/ and I'm still getting the same outcome on my laptop when I try to boot.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create it with dd on a Mac. I have done this successfully with an Arch Linux ISO. Make sure the output destination is the USB device, not a partition on the device.